# Regex help - match words besides MD5 hashes

Tags: regex

I can't figure out a regex that will grab every word besides MD5 hashes. - I'm using `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` to match every word. How do I augment that so that it ignores something I'm thinking is like `[a-fA-F0-9]{32}` which would match the MD5 hashes. My question regards Regex.

```
8e85d8b3be426bc8d370facdb0ad3ad0
string
stringString
63994b32affec18c2a428cdfcb0e2823
stringSTRINGSTING333
34563994b32dddddddaffec18c2a
stringSTRINGSTINGsrting
```

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: I think you're not being very clear. Do you want to match a word at either end of an MD5 hash, every text that's not MD5 or something else? You might want to give a clear example of what you want to do and not how you were try doing it.

Comment: do you mean if the passed in string is an MD5 hash, then do something (or nothing), if not MD5 hash, then do something else?   Can the pass in string have both an MD5 and then some text after it?

Comment: made myself more clear sorry about that

Comment: Look for something that's not ([0-9]|[a-f]|[A-F]){32}

Comment: why are you trying to override `String` object? and din't you forget quotation marks around your `8e85d8b3be426bc8d370facdb0ad3ad0`? i still don't see much relevance of your code to your question

Comment: that code had* nothing to do with it, i've replaced it with pure example text

Comment: @Luke we still don't know what you have. if it's one big string, or list..

Comment: What Dave said, Ignore the parts that matches the regex. Seems fairly easy.

Comment: Yes that would make since, but I don't know how to construct the Regex to do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing is usually done with a negative lookahead:

```
/\b(?![0-9a-f]{32}\b)[A-Za-z0-9]+\b/
```

At the beginning of each word, `(?![0-9a-fA-F]{32}\b)` tries to match exactly 32 hexadecimal digits followed by a word boundary.  If it succeeds, the regex fails.

Comment: +1 for a pure regex solution, although [A-Za-z0-9] may need to be changed if you consider "Hello!" a word to be matched rather than just "Hello" (and not the exclamation point).

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me:

```
/^[a-f0-9]{8}(-)[a-f0-9]{4}(-)[a-f0-9]{4}(-)[a-f0-9]{4}(-)[a-f0-9]{12}$/i
```

Comment: That would match a MD5 hash in the form `8e85d8b3-be42-6bc8-d370-facdb0ad3ad0`.

However, the question was how to *not* match any MD5 hashes.

Answer (score 0):

as already said, just grab all words which do not match to be MD5 hashes.
(first, you have to split the string)

```
var s = "8e85d8b3be426bc8d370facdb0ad3ad0\nstring\nstringString\n63994b32affec18c2a428cdfcb0e2823\nstringSTRINGSTING333\n34563994b32dddddddaffec18c2a\nstringSTRINGSTINGsrting";

words = [];
words_all = s.split(/\s+/);
for (i in words_all) {
  word = words_all[i];
  if (! word.match(/^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$/)) { words.push(word) }
}
// words = ["string", "stringString", "stringSTRINGSTING333", "34563994b32dddddddaffec18c2a", "stringSTRINGSTINGsrting"]
```

(assuming, according to your original code, you want to use javascript)